# CPython/wxWidgets front-end using Java6 jar

Tags: python, wxpython, jython

How can I use the functionality of a Java library I have in JAR format (no sources) in a wxPython front-end app running on OS X 10.8?

I can use the library in Jython, everything works fine, but of course `wx` is CPython-only so I could not find anything better than this: http://jpype.sourceforge.net/doc/user-guide/userguide.html :(

Needless to say, JPype is really cumbersome, at least for the extensive use I need to make of the JAR in question.. are there better ways to do this or more advanced systems?

I can't change wxPython as the GUI as all the toolchain depends on it, up to the latest packaging step of PyInstaller.. and I can't rewrite the JAR nor replace it with some open-source package..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest running it in a different process as a java application, and then communicate with the Python application using some form of IPC.